# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional, works in sim crashes on iPhone

Tags: swift, error-handling, option-type

HI guys getting a well known error while unwrapping an optional error. Ran in debugger mode and it falls down at the line below. Im using an implicit unwrap which I thought would be fine here as I am definitely selecting a date. Works in the simulator but not on the iPhone.

im guessing I can use an if let statement to be on the safe side, just wondered how I would implement this and am looking for some assistance.

Hope someone can help

Many thanks

```
if startDateTextField.text == "" || endDateTextField == "" {

        let alert2 = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message: "Please Select an End Date!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert2.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert2, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {

    let start = String(startDateTextField.text)
    let end = String(endDateTextField.text)
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"

    guard let startDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(start), endDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(end) else {
            print("error")
            return
        }

    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calendar.components([.Day], fromDate: startDate, toDate: endDate, options: [])
    let days = components.day
    let weeks = components.day / 7
    let weeksanddays = days % 7
    let newString = "\(weeks) weeks + \(weeksanddays) days"
    resultWeeksAndDays.text = newString
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `!` on a task that may produce errors. You can't just believe that transforming any string from the input (that user gives!) will be the transformed to `NSDate()`. You can even have something lacking in the data format or even in input constraints. Just use `if let` instead of explicitly unwrapping the optionals, or even better, use guard. What to do exactly?

Instead of :

```
let startDate: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(start)!
let endDate: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(end)!
```

Do:

```
guard let startDat = dateFormatter.dateFromString(start), endDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(end) else {
    // You don't have dates, show error, do no nothing - your choice.
    return
}
```

And after the block you are 100% sure you get the objects. Are they correct? Probably yes if the formatter you specified is correct. But you have objects, and thats the fact. Now you can proceed with your operations.

To be honest, you should also do the same checks with the string getters from UI objects (these two below), because you may delete one from the view and bam..

```
let start = String(startDateTextField.text!)
let end = String(endDateTextField.text!)
```

Comment: many thanks, great that has stopped the error but its not printing to the lable, I'm getting an error in the console (which I'm printing) doing something wrong obviously :-(

Comment: It means that the strings you want to parse to dates are not in correct format, and the parsing returns nil object. But this is another question, completely unrelated to this one, so please create a new one with complete description and I'm pretty sure someone will help.